# Plug the dynamic xml to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I have a timeline javascript that gets the data from xml.
I managed to write the xml generator. Timeline, when it feeds from the xml, works fine.

But when I connect the xml generator instead of XML file it fails. I checked, the generator outputs correct data(I saved it to XML file and checked the timeline plugin)

```
//WORKS: 
Timeline.loadXML("./example.xml", function(xml, url) { eventSource.loadXML(xml, url); })

//DOES NOT WORK
Timeline.loadXML("./TimelineReportXML.php", function(xml, url) { eventSource.loadXML(xml, url); })
```

What is wrong? Javascript can't get the XML from file that has the .php extension? What are my options?

Comment: I guess your PHP has header() output correctly XML headers?

Comment: worked! thank you. Post as answer

Comment: see you got an answer anyway glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP you need to add the XML content type header :

```
header('Content-type: application/xml');
```

This line must be included in your PHP script prior to any output.

Comment: I added: `header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"); ` and it worked. Thank you.